# Azure App Service API CORS Policy not working

Tags: azure, cors, azure-web-app-service

I have a .NET Core API hosted on Azure (azure app service) and it is running behind APIM. I now need to call this API from a front-end (again using the APIM endpoint) and I have been unable to set up CORS properly. I do not want to define CORS in code - my .NET code has zero CORS policy setup.

CORS is set up at the app service level by adding the allowed origins in the CORS blade but the preflight request still comes without CORS header when calling the API through APIM (thus I get "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check..."). I have added a CORS policy to the APIM instance for All Operations for the respective API but it still does not work. The "Options" request comes back without the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header on the browser debugger. If I skip APIM and call the API directly, it works fine. Am I missing something obvious here?

[image: cors policy in app service]
CORS Policy in APIM:

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <cors>
            <allowed-origins>
                <origin>*</origin>
            </allowed-origins>
            <allowed-methods>
                <method>GET</method>
                <method>POST</method>
                <method>OPTIONS</method>
                <method>TRACE</method>
                <method>PUT</method>
                <method>DELETE</method>
                <method>HEAD</method>
                <method>PATCH</method>
            </allowed-methods>
            <allowed-headers>
                <header>*</header>
            </allowed-headers>
        </cors>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
        <set-header name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" exists-action="override">
            <value>*</value>
        </set-header>
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

Note that I also tried to specifically add the front-end URL https://frontend.com in those settings and check Allow Credentials checkbox, which also changed nothing.

When I added the set-header option, if I directly call the API via postman then the Access-Control-Allow-Origin is returned on the postman call, but on the browser preflight request still nothing.

[image: debugger]

**EDIT:**

Per response.. I tried to simplify the scenario by creating a brand new API with the template "weather forecast" .net core api deployed to it. No authentication and CORS policy set to *. I proceeded to add this API to my APIM instance - simply clicked the App Service option in the APIM menu and added CORS policy - nothing else. Then, in a separate URL (for CORS to trigger) I deployed a simple HTML with a call to the new APIM endpoint. The headers look exactly the same - no CORS header and the call fails, if I skip APIM and call backend directly it works. I cannot spot any error in my set up at this point, no idea what I may be missing. Screenshots below

[image: app service setup]
[image: apim]
[image: apim 2]
[image: request failure]

Comment: Still struggling with this. I tested bypassing APIM and CORS works properly when directly calling the backend so the problem seems to be APIM itself. No matter what policies I try to set, the options request always comes back without any headers as above. I tried to forward options requests (route *) to back end but it also did not work.

Comment: Is there any progress?

Comment: Edited with new 'clean' test

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have finally found the issue. When you create an API Management instance, usually you'll also need a portal for users to view your schemas, subscribe to your API and test it in the browser. To do this, once the APIM instance is created, you just have to go to the Portal Overview section and click Publish + Enable CORS, which I did for our API. What this actually does is that it sets a CORS policy with origin=Portal URL at the "All APIs" level and this policy overwrites any CORS policy you might set at an API/method level.

Unfortunately, I never considered that there might be any policies defined at the "All APIs" level so I never even clicked there. Additionally, there is no warning on the interface that one might be there nor that it overwrites policies at a lower level. Once I set the proper origin at the "All APIs" level, everything worked perfectly. Hope this helps someone with similar issues!

[image]

Comment: This information helped me, even though the root cause was not the same. I did not have the developer portal CORS configuration enabled. But when I enabled it I could also add other allowed origins next to the developer portal URL, and FINALLY it started working, even though I'm certain I had gone through all the levels and checked the calculated effective policy. Anyway, I want to recommend this guide for troubleshooting similar issues: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-paas-blog/how-to-troubleshoot-cors-error-in-azure-api-management-service/ba-p/2241695

Answer (score 3):

It seems you can access your api successfully, but cannot see the response header you set. **The problem might be that you hide some response header in your code.**

**My suggestion is:**

Check the response header by browse your app service url: `https://yourbackend.azurewebsites.net/`. If the response header just two elements like your final picture, then the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` would not appear.

**_____________________________________________________________________________**

**For testing:**

I created a back-end api project and a front-end project to call the api, and publish them to separate app service.

Then, test to call the api from front-end app, it failed with this **ERROR**:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'back-end url' from origin 'front-end url' has been blocked by CORS policy:
```

After configuring the CORS option on portal, calling "`https://myfront-end.azurewebsites.net/home/test`", which worked as expected.
**_____________________________________________________________________________**

**Now, it comes to the APIM part:**

1. I created an APIM and add my back-end app service as an API:
   [image]
2. Configure the settings to include my app service url:
   [image]
3. Configure CORS policy with yours:
   [image]

4.Modify the API's endpoint to my front-end project:
[image]

5. Which works fine with the header "`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`" you said:
   [image]

Comment: See edit - I tried what seems to be exactly what you did and still cant get it to work. Am I somehow just not seeing an obvious mistake somewhere?

Comment: Does it only show this two response headers even if you run it without any settings on portal?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, missed notification on response. Yes, I tried several combinations of settings in the portal including removing everything (API Management settings) and it always returns only these two headers.

Comment: That's the problem. It's not the APIM's fault, but your original code's fault. Search **"hide response header in c#"** for more information.

Comment: How come? I am currently bypassing APIM due to this issue and all headers are present in my responses directly from the API itself. It's only when I switch to calling the same API via APIM that they disappear and only for OPTIONS call as I shown before. There's no code to remove headers in my API whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

I am running into the same issue.

If I set the "allowed methods" in the "inbound policy" like you have and try to do a PATCH, I get the error as you do and the response header of pre-flight request does not have anything other than the two that you see.

However, if I change the "allowed methods" inbound policy to * and remove GET, POST, OPTIONS etc.., then the preflight request has all the response headers as expected:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxhnO.png)

You should try setting "*" for allowed methods in the inbound policy.(As a side note, I do not have any "set headers" in outbound policy)

Note:
I get "Method patch is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response." even though it's present in the response header.

Answer (score 0):

One further consideration is where you have placed your CORS policy in APIM. I tried all of the above approaches, but I still say the CORS pre-flight warnings. In our case we offer an API product so don't have the option of locking down to our own domains. The following snippet from the Azure API Management policy reference docs resolved the issue for me.

> Policy order - You may experience unexpected behavior if the cors policy is not the first policy in the inbound section. Select Calculate effective policy in the policy editor to check the policy evaluation order at each scope. Generally, only the first cors policy is applied.

We were applying the policy at the API level - this looked like:

```
<policies>
  <inbound>
    <base />
    <cors>
       ...
    </cors>
  </inbound>
```

The offending piece here was the <base /> was applying product and global polices before the API CORS were reviewed. As the docs state this can cause expected behaviour. Two options exist, move the policy to global, this is not always ideal; or swap the order of the <cors /> and <base /> tags like below:

```
<policies>
  <inbound>
    <cors>
       ...
    </cors>
    <base />
  </inbound>
```

I found this worked immediately.